# Horizontal rule with adjustable height behaving like \cline{n-m}

Tags: tables, rules

How can I produce `\noalign{\hrule height 1pt}` only through a certain number of columns just like with `\cline{n-m}` (or basically `\cline` with adjustable thickness)?

[image: The objective.]

**Fig. 1:** The approximate objective (digitally manipulated in a graphics editing program).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can define a new command which changes the value of `\arrayrulewidth`, draws the `\cline` and then restores `\arrayrulewidth` to its original value:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}
\newcommand{\Cline}[2]{%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}{\arrayrulewidth}}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{#1}}\cline{#2}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\Oldarrayrulewidth}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  a & b & c \\\Cline{2pt}{2-3}
  d & e & f \\\Cline{3pt}{1-2}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first argument of `\Cline` controls the "thickness" of the rule.

EDIT: The `\cmidrule` command provided by the `booktabs` package admits an optional argument controlling the thickness of the rule, so you can say:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  a & b & c \\ \cmidrule[2pt]{2-3}
  d & e & f \\ \cmidrule[3pt]{1-2}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to have any effect when used with the `\multirow` command from the [*multirow* package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow).

Comment: If I load the `mathtools` package, this doesn't seem to work... any ideas?

Comment: Creating a new command is an elegant solution, and avoids using yet another package.

`booktabs` is a good solution, provided you don't use vertical lines, which the package creator refuses to implement.

Answer (score 4):

You may have a look at the [tabu](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package. It supports optional parameters for the width of the rules in a table.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow,tabu}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\rb}[1]{\raisebox{2ex}{\smash{#1}}}
\setlength{\extrarowsep}{10pt}

\begin{document}
  \scriptsize
  \noindent
  \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {|[1pt] c|[1pt] c|[1pt] p{4cm} | X |[1pt]}\tabucline[1pt]{-}
    \multirow{4}{*}[-5ex]{\rotatebox{90}{Ten}} & \multirow{2}{*}[-2ex]{\rotatebox{90}{Eight}} & \rb{One} & \rb{Two} \\ \tabucline{3-4}
    & & \rb{Three} & \rb{Four} \\[2ex] \tabucline[1pt]{2-4}
    & \multirow{2}{*}[-2ex]{\rotatebox{90}{Nine}} & \rb{Five} & \rb{Six} \\ \tabucline{3-4}
    & &\multicolumn{2}{l|[1pt]}{\rb{Seven}} \\[4ex] \tabucline[1pt]{-}
  \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am indeed impressed by your solution of almost all issues I currently have. It is unfortunate that I did not come across the `tabu` package before, it looks very promising. There is just one more issue: If I want some of the rules thicker (as in your code), there are gaps between them. Do you know how to make them join seamlessly, please?

Comment: I see what you mean. And I'm afraid that this is an issue that is better addressed to the package maintainer.

Comment: I have just accidentally solved it by simply replacing `\tabucline` with `\cline` and `\Cline` defined by @Gonzalo Medina hereinbefore. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

With package  `colortbl` , you may redefine the thickness of `\hline` and `\cline`.

The example below is adapted from page 6 of the manual for `colortbl`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{colortbl}        
\begin{document}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}\arrayrulecolor{blue}

  \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \hline
          one   & two\\
          three & four\\
      \cline{1-1}
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use this answer just for one `\clie` in one table, and don't change other lines and other tables?
`\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}\arrayrulecolor{blue}`

Comment: The color can be changed within a table using \arrayrulecolor{myColor} anywhere in the table. The thickness seems to be set for the entire table. See documentation of `colortbl`.