# Variable-width horizontal rules with \cline intrude cell text

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, rules

I have come to learn how to make a variable-width horizontal rule with **\hline** from the LaTeX companion and with **\cline** from [Horizontal rule with adjustable height behaving like \cline{n-m}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24549/horizontal-rule-with-adjustable-height-behaving-like-clinen-m). But the problem with the horizontal **\cline** is that the rule intrudes on the texts in the cells below the **\cline**. However, **\hline** doesn't seem to have this intruding problem. The minimal working example below shows the differences.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{I}{!{\vrule width 3pt}}
\newlength\savedwidth
\newcommand\whline{\noalign{\global\savedwidth\arrayrulewidth\global\arrayrulewidth 6pt}%
\hline
\noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\savedwidth}}
\begin{tabular}{|cIc|c|}\hline
A & B & C \\ \hline
X & Y & Z \\ \whline
100 & 10 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\renewcommand\whline[1]{\noalign{\global\savedwidth\arrayrulewidth\global\arrayrulewidth 6pt}%
\cline{#1}
\noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\savedwidth}}
\begin{tabular}{|cIc|c|}\hline
 A & B & C \\ \hline
 X & Y & Z \\ \whline{1-3}
 100 & 10 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Top picture essentially used \hline; bottom one used \cline.]

Another problem with using **\cline** in the definition of the thick horizontal rule (*whline* above) is that a **\cellcolor** command will wipe out the portion of the horizontal rule that is above the cell, no matter how thick I defined the *whline* to be. Using **\hline** in the definition of *whline* does not cause this problem with using colors in a cell.

I suspect that the vertical position, starting below which is the territory of a cell,  for **\hline** and for **\cline** differs. For **\hline**, a cell starts below the bottom boundary of the horizontal rule, while for **\cline**, a cell starts below the top boundary of the rule? Anyone enlighten me please!

**NOTE**: I do want to use variable-width **\cline** (either thick or thin like the example showed), but I want to avoid these intruding problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both problems are related. `\cline` has to support several `\cline`s in a row, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\cline{5-5}
    A & B & C & D & E
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Example \cline]

Therefore `\cline` cannot move down like `\hline`, the definition of `\cline` is (`latex.ltx`):

```
\def\cline#1{\@cline#1\@nil}
\def\@cline#1-#2\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#2%
  \advance\@multicnt-#1%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
  \cr
  \noalign{\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}
```

In the last step `\cline` moves back to the original vertical position.

But the vertical space for the line can be added after the `\cline`s, e.g.:

```
\cline{...}\cline{...}\noalign{\vskip\arrayrulewidth}
```

Applied to your example, it can be added to macro `\whline`. This fixes also the problem with `\cellcolor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{I}{!{\vrule width 3pt}}
\newlength\savedwidth

\newcommand\whline[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \global\savedwidth\arrayrulewidth\global\arrayrulewidth 6pt%
  }%
  \cline{#1}%
  \noalign{\vskip\arrayrulewidth}%
  \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\savedwidth}%
}
\begin{tabular}{|cIc|c|}\hline
 A & B & C \\ \hline
 X & \cellcolor{red}Y & Z \\ \whline{1-3}
 \cellcolor{green}100 & 10 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! I guess it's time for me to learn some plain TeX to really understand what is going on under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

Here is Heiko's example using `cals` package as an alternative:

[image: cals table with variable borders and color]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{cals}
\begin{document}
\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{10mm}{10mm}{10mm}}
\makeatletter
\brow
\cell{A}
\def\cals@borderL{2pt}\cell{B}\let\cals@borderL=\relax
\cell{C}
\erow
\brow
\def\cals@borderB{3pt}
\cell{X}
\def\cals@borderL{2pt}\def\cals@bgcolor{red}
 \cell{Y}\let\cals@borderL=\relax\def\cals@bgcolor{}
\cell{Z}
\erow
\let\cals@borderB=\relax
\brow
\def\cals@bgcolor{green}\cell{100}\def\cals@bgcolor{}
\def\cals@borderL{2pt}\cell{10}\let\cals@borderL=\relax
\cell{1}
\erow
\end{calstable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This package looks hard to use... But it seems very flexible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The package `nicematrix` provides an environment `{NiceTabular}`, and, in this environment, the command `\cline` has been redefined to change that behaviour.

So, your code works as expected in `{NiceTabular}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{I}{!{\vrule width 3pt}}
\newlength\savedwidth
\newcommand\whline[1]
   {\noalign{\global\savedwidth\arrayrulewidth\global\arrayrulewidth 6pt}%
    \cline{#1}
    \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\savedwidth}}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|cIc|c|}
\hline
 A & B & C \\ \hline
 X & Y & Z \\ \whline{1-3}
 100 & 10 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Outuput of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{|c|[3pt]c|c|}
 \hline
   A   & B  & C    \\
 \cline[3pt]{1-2}
   X   & Y  & Z    \\
 \hline[6pt]
   100 & 10 & 1 \\
 \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]