# Why is this \@ifstar construction not working, when both constituent \cline-like macros work?

Tags: tables, macros, starred-version

I have a macro that makes a `\cline` of user-specified thickness. I want to create a `*` and un-`*` version to account for the difference between [two cases depending on whether there is more than one `\cline` in a sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124158/7922) (e.g., `\cline{1-2}\cline{5-6}`). (When the `\cline` rules are thick, they can clobber part/all of content of the row beneath unless there's a correcting `\vskip` at the end.)

The unstarred version adds this `\vskip` at the end, and you'd use it for the last `\cline` of a sequence (which subsumes the case where it's the only `\cline`). The starred version omits this `\vskip`, and you'd use it for all but the final `\cline` in a sequence. In the below code, `\ClineTStar` is that starred macro without the `\vskip` correction. I then define `\ClineTNoStar`to simply call `\ClineTStar` and add the correcting `\vskip` at the end.

These differently named versions of the macro are working fine, when I call them with their distinct names. See the output below. The starred `\cline`s after the row starting with `A & …` undesirably clobber the row underneath (that should start with `I & J & K…`). But the `\cline`s after row `Q & R…` (which is two starred followed by one unstarred macro) properly leave room for the next row's content `Y & Z…`

But I'd like to call this pair of macros as `\ClineT*` and `\ClineT`. When I follow the traditional `\@ifstar` approach to create these flavors, and call either version, I get an error message like:

> Misplaced \omit.
>   \@ClineTStar #1-#2#3\@nil ->\omit 
>                                     \@multicnt #1\advance \@multispan \m@ne \i...
>   l.36 \ClineT*{1-2}{10pt}
>                            \ClineT*{4-5}{10pt} \ClineT{7-8}{10pt}

I've commented out the line `\ClineT*{1-2}{10pt} \ClineT*{4-5}{10pt} \ClineT{7-8}{10pt}` so that it will compile.

What am I doing wrong? (I don't want to use LaTeX3 methods, because, AFAIK, that's not compatible with Overleaf v1. So I'd like to fix this `\@ifstar` approach.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\ClineTStar#1#2{\@ClineTStar#1#2\@nil}
\def\@ClineTStar#1-#2#3\@nil{%
    \omit
    \@multicnt#1%
    \advance\@multispan\m@ne
    \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
    \@multicnt#2%
    \advance\@multicnt-#1%
    \advance\@multispan\@ne
    \leaders\hrule\@height#3\hfill
    \cr
    \noalign{\vskip-#3}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\ClineTNoStar}[2]{%
    \ClineTStar{#1}{#2}%
    \noalign{\vskip#2}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ClineT}{\@ifstar{\ClineTStar}{\ClineTNoStar}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
\ClineTStar{1-2}{10pt} \ClineTStar{4-5}{10pt} \ClineTStar{7-8}{10pt}
I & J & K & L & M & N & O & P \\
Q & R & S & T & U & V & W & X \\
\ClineTStar{1-2}{10pt} \ClineTStar{4-5}{10pt} \ClineTNoStar{7-8}{10pt}
Y & Z & A & B & C & D & E & F \\
%\ClineT*{1-2}{10pt} \ClineT*{4-5}{10pt} \ClineT{7-8}{10pt}
E & F & G & H & I & J & K & L \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your question: I don’t think your implementation will work well with `\ClineTStar{9-11}{10pt}`.

Comment: @RuixiZhang, it doesn't like the corresponding `\cline{9-11}` either. I'm happy if this works in the cases that `\cline` accepts.

Comment: The original `\@cline` has two markers: Everything that comes before `-` is `#1`; everything after `-` but before `\@nil` is `#2`. It breaks down in your code since `#2` can only be one token.

Comment: @RuixiZhang, what I was referring to is that {9-11} means "span from column 9 through column 11." In my example, there are only 8 columns. Neither my macro nor `\cline` works gracefully here when you specify an out-of-bounds column range. Mine seems to work fine for column ranges that are feasible.

Comment: I see. I was referring to the situation when you have 10 or more columns. This implementation is an equivalence of a ticking time bomb. In the case of an 11-column table with `\ClineTStar{9-11}{10pt}`, your `\@ClineTStar` would grab `9` as `#1`, `1` as `#2` and `110pt` as `#3`.

Comment: @RuixiZhang, you're absolutely correct! I appreciate your pointing out this problem. Rather than take `110pt` as `#3` (or rather even if it did), since 1<9, it doesn't even draw a line in this case. I should consider perhaps reordering my argument order to use `\ClineTStar{10pt}{9-11}`.

Comment: Well, a quick hack would be to use `\ClineTStar{9-{11}}{10pt}` with an extra pair of `{}` around whatever integer following the `-`. This is not a *great* idea, though.

Comment: Question with similar cause → [tables - Multicolumn error when used within a newcommand with \@ifstar - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67947/multicolumn-error-when-used-within-a-newcommand-with-ifstar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `\omit` really must be the first command that appears in the tabular cell after `\\`. If you use macros there, they have to be fully expandable and `\omit` has to be the very first token of that expansion. As `\@ifstar` uses several assignments before it can make the decision if the next token is `*`, it will fail here. So we have to replace `\ClineT` by a fully expandable macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\ClineTStar#1#2{\@ClineTStar#1#2\@nil}
\def\@ClineTStar#1-#2#3\@nil{%
    \omit
    \@multicnt#1%
    \advance\@multispan\m@ne
    \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
    \@multicnt#2%
    \advance\@multicnt-#1%
    \advance\@multispan\@ne
    \leaders\hrule\@height#3\hfill
    \cr
    \noalign{\vskip-#3}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\ClineTNoStar}[2]{%
    \ClineTStar{#1}{#2}%
    \noalign{\vskip#2}%
}

\makeatletter
\def\ClineT#1{%
    \expandafter\ifx\@firstofmany#1\relax\@end*%
        \expandafter\ClineTStar
    \else
        \ClineT@#1%
    \fi
}
\def\ClineT@#1\fi{\fi\ClineTNoStar{#1}}
\def\@firstofmany#1#2\@end{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
\ClineTStar{1-2}{10pt} \ClineTStar{4-5}{10pt} \ClineTStar{7-8}{10pt}
I & J & K & L & M & N & O & P \\
Q & R & S & T & U & V & W & X \\
\ClineTStar{1-2}{10pt} \ClineTStar{4-5}{10pt} \ClineTNoStar{7-8}{10pt}
Y & Z & A & B & C & D & E & F \\
\ClineT*{1-2}{10pt} \ClineT*{4-5}{10pt} \ClineT{7-8}{10pt}
E & F & G & H & I & J & K & L \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\ClineT` takes one argument that will be either `*` or a group like `{1-2}`. We find the first token of that argument using the helper macro `\*firstofmany` and compare it against `*`. If they are the same, `\ClineTStar` is the next thing to be called.

A bit trickier is the other branch because we need to re-apply the already read argument to `\ClineTNoStar`. Simply `\else\ClineTNoStar{#1}\fi` won't work—now `\fi` would become the second argument of `\ClineTNoStar`. The solution is to use a helper macro that uses `\fi` as delimited parameter, immediately puts it back to the token stream and calls the actual macro as the final part of the expansion.

Comment: A beautiful answer. +1

Comment: That certainly fixes it! This is area of TeX knowledge that I know little about, so it's somewhat Greek to me, but I'm very happy to have the solution.