# How to modify this table with multirow

Tags: tables

I want to get the table of the following image, I currently have the table but I am missing the part that is drawn

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{boldline} 

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\def\arraystretch{2.2}%
\begin{tabular}{V{4}p{25mm}|c|c|c|p{25mm}|c|c|cV{4}}
  \hlineB{3}
  \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{V{4}cV{1}}{aaaaa} & \multicolumn{4}{cV{4}}{aaaaa} \\ \hline

  \hline
  \rowcolor{cyan}
  1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
   1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
     \hline
   1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\


  \hlineB{4}
\end{tabular}
\endgroup


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing as few things as possible:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{boldline} 

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24552/166457
% change the width of a cline
\newlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}
\newcommand{\Cline}[2]{%
    \noalign{\global\setlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}{\arrayrulewidth}}%
    \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{#1}}\cline{#2}%
    \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\Oldarrayrulewidth}}}

\begin{document}

    \begingroup
    \def\arraystretch{2.2}%
    \begin{tabular}{V{4}p{10mm}|p{10mm}|p{25mm}|c|c|c|p{25mm}|c|c|cV{4}}
        \hlineB{3}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{}   & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{4}{V{1}cV{1}}{aaaaa} & \multicolumn{4}{cV{4}}{aaaaa}  \\
%       \hline
    %   \rowcolor{cyan}
    & & \cellcolor{cyan} 1 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-1 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-2 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-2 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-1 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-2 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-2 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-2 \\
        \hline
    & & 1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
        \hline
    & & 1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
        \hlineB{4}
    \end{tabular}
    \endgroup


\end{document}
```

results in:

[image: table]

using nice code from [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina)

Comment: I only replied because I have fun in doing so - well aware that the question was not the prime example of how to ask here. Next time, try to show where your problem is - please don't just write "Do this". This does not feel right :)